# Merge pyspark data frame rows with one column value different

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to merge two dataframe rows with one column value different. For example,

DataframeA:

```
firstName lastName age 
Alex      Smith    19
Rick      Mart     18
```

DataframeB:

```
firstName lastName age 
Alex      Smith    21
```

Result when I use merge DataframeA with DataframeB using `union`:

```
firstName lastName age 
Alex      Smith    19
Rick      Mart     18
Alex      Smith    21
```

What I want is that the rows with all column values same but different age should get combined as well, in a way that the age column has the max value. So, this is what I expect -

```
firstName lastName age 
Alex      Smith    21
Rick      Mart     18
```

Anyway I can achieve this in PySpark?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `union` you can easily aggregate the resultant set get the `max` of `age`

#### Data Preparation

```
s1 = StringIO("""
firstName,lastName,age
Alex,Smith,19
Rick,Mart,18
""")


df1 = pd.read_csv(s1,delimiter=',')

sparkDF1 = sql.createDataFrame(df1)


s2 = StringIO("""
firstName,lastName,age
Alex,Smith,21
""")


df2 = pd.read_csv(s2,delimiter=',')

sparkDF2 = sql.createDataFrame(df2)

sparkDF1.show()

+---------+--------+---+
|firstName|lastName|age|
+---------+--------+---+
|     Alex|   Smith| 19|
|     Rick|    Mart| 18|
+---------+--------+---+

sparkDF2.show()

+---------+--------+---+
|firstName|lastName|age|
+---------+--------+---+
|     Alex|   Smith| 21|
+---------+--------+---+
```

#### Union & Max

```
sparkDF1.union(sparkDF2)\
        .groupBy(['firstName','lastName']).agg(F.max(F.col('age')).alias('age'))\
        .show()

+---------+--------+---+
|firstName|lastName|age|
+---------+--------+---+
|     Alex|   Smith| 21|
|     Rick|    Mart| 18|
+---------+--------+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a full join as well. you'll need to retain the `greatest` of the 2 ages (from 2 dataframes).

here's the example - *I've added an additional row in the second dataframe that is not available in the first dataframe*

```py
data1_sdf.alias('a'). \
    join(data2_sdf.alias('b'), ['firstname', 'lastname'], 'full'). \
    selectExpr('firstname', 'lastname', 'greatest(a.age, b.age) as age'). \
    show()

# +---------+--------+---+
# |firstname|lastname|age|
# +---------+--------+---+
# |     Rick|   Smart| 20|
# |     Alex|   Smith| 21|
# |     Rick|    Mart| 18|
# +---------+--------+---+
```

---

dataframes used

```
+---------+--------+---+
|firstname|lastname|age|
+---------+--------+---+
|     Alex|   Smith| 19|
|     Rick|    Mart| 18|
+---------+--------+---+

+---------+--------+---+
|firstname|lastname|age|
+---------+--------+---+
|     Alex|   Smith| 21|
|     Rick|   Smart| 20|
+---------+--------+---+
```